# Getting Number of ALM user connected

Tags: hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center, application-lifecycle, hp-alm

I am trying to get number of user connections and License used in a ALM. I was able to accomplish it using Site Admin Console and SQL Queries.
Is there a way where I can get it apart from above 2 solutions.
I also tried to automate the same monitoring using UFT which I was not able to do as the web properties of  HP ALM is dynamically changing on a particular time interval.

**DB Query used to get no of user connected**

```
SELECT STATUS, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS
GROUP BY STATUS
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with ALM SAClient API, you can retrieve this information by calling GetConnections. SAClient API is a COM technology library, you can invoke it by .Net Framework interop technology. There is no other way to achieve this purpose.